# Presentation Software

Tags: education

I would like to make a series of mathematical lessons to upload on YouTube. Many mathematical lessons on YouTube that I've watched just video film a presentation on blackboard or paper. The disadvantage is that it is not easily editable. Is there any software application (or a combination of applications) that makes it easy to make beautiful mathematical presentations?

Comment: [Latex/beamer](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations#The_Beamer_package) is a common choice for many.

Comment: Yes. I too am thinking of Beamer. Showing Beamer slides with oral explanation would be nice. But I am not sure if you are asking something else.

Comment: Could you provide a link to a presentation made with Beamer? One that shows it's capabilities. I would also like to know if you can sync the speaker voice and the slides. I mean if I prerecord speaker sound how can I sync it with the different parts of the slides.

Answer (score 4):

Note: This solution is for Mac only. There are some programs for Linux/BSD that are similar to LaTeXiT but my experience with them has been less than stellar.

I know that people really love Beamer and other TeX presentation programs but they have a big flaw (in my mind): They don't let you customize the design of your presentation.

I recommend Keynote + LaTeXiT. You can make some very beautiful Keynote presentations and LaTeXiT [0] lets you add in math to documents as SVGs (e.g. you get control of how big your equations are without image degredation).

The person who inspired me to make the switch is Daniel Baumann [1]. His website has tons of examples.

[0] LaTeXiT: http://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/
[1] Baumann: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/.... Examples of his presentations can be found here: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/...

Please also refer to the following link:https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-to-make-a-presentation-that-includes-math-symbols

Comment: When I click on the link http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/ that you've provided it says Error-Forbidden. Could you provide some other link to a presentation mede with LatexiT?

Answer (score 2):

Update: I've recently discovered and fallen in love with a newish software, so I'd like to promote it. [Quarto](https://quarto.org/) makes presentations, websites, notebooks, and so on -- I've found it to be quick and easy to make documents that look great.  Source files are primarily written in Markdown, and perhaps if you need the extra features, with some YAML, CSS, or other very familiar languages and codes.

From that baseline if you want to style them or adjust functionality there's a lot of power to do that, and only takes about as much time and effort as is proportionate to how much you want to accomplish.

Can't recommend it enough.

---

Things I've experimented with, to greater and lesser success, but I'll just list them all so that you can judge for yourself what is best:

1. Notion
2. RevealJS
3. Obsidian
4. Jupyter notebooks
5. MathBeret
6. Goodnotes/Nebo/Apple Notes/Notable
7. OneNote
8. Manim
9. Pandoc

I personally am currently using Notion for my lectures, but if MathBeret becomes more stable and looks nicer or is easier to use, I may switch.

Answer (score 1):

This may seem lame, but there is a free powerpoint add-in that inserts $\LaTeX$ math as pictures and allows editing.

Go to [IguanaTex](http://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/) and download the addin. The toolbar has two main buttons. **New** and **Edit** equations for adding a new equation, or editing an existing one.

[image: Toolbar]

Here is what the edit looks like on the screen:

[image: MainScreen]